# Ignore a specific folder pattern in testMatch with Jest

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, pattern-matching, jestjs

I'm trying to ignore a specific folder in the `testMatch` pattern of Jest.

I have my tests in a `__tests__` folder and I want to be able to have a folder `__config__` into it with all files inside which should be ignored.

```
/__tests__
  /__config__
    someConfig.jsx
  /MyComponent.jsx
/MyComponent.jsx
```

My tests in the `__tests__` folder will import the files from the `__config__` folder so I don't want to ignore them with the `transformIgnorePatterns`.

But if I don't ignore the folder, Jest tries to run in the folder and returns an error:

> FAIL `src/components/__tests__/__config__/someConfig.jsx`
>
> Your test suite must contain at least one test.

I've tried a few different patterns but I can't find a way to ignore the `__config__` folder

```
testMatch: [
  "**/__tests__/!(__config__)/**/*.(js)?(x)", // Doesn't work
  "**/__tests__/(**|!__config__)/*.(js)?(x)", // Doesn't work
  "**/__tests__/(**|?!__config__)/*.(js)?(x)", // Doesn't work
  "**/__tests__/{**,!__config__}/*.(js)?(x)", // Doesn't work
],
```

Any idea how I can ignore the sub-folder like this?

Comment: Damn, I just liked your question @alexmngn

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Try to use `testPathIgnorePatterns`, instead.

If the test path matches any of the patterns, it will be skipped.

Use the  string token to include the path to your project's root.

Answer (score 0):

You can also exclude files in the `testMatch` array using negation `!`. For example:

```js
'testMatch': [
    '**/__tests__/**/*.+(ts|tsx|js)',
    '!**/excludeMe.ts'
  ],
```

Note that the order matters.

> Each glob pattern is applied in the order they are specified in the config. For example ["!**/**fixtures**/**", "**/**tests**/**/*.js"] will not exclude **fixtures** because the negation is overwritten with the second pattern. In order to make the negated glob work in this example it has to come after **/**tests**/**/*.js.

https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration#testmatch-arraystring

Answer (score -1):

Try This pattern:

> testMatch: ['**/--tests--/?(*.)(test).js?(x)'],

It is working for me.
My folder structure is:
--tests--
  auth.test.js
  user.test.js
Routes
 -
 -
Anotherfolders.